# $\exp^{-1}(V)=\bigcup U_n$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that given $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $V=B_{|z|}(z)$ open ball then $\exp^{-1}(V)=\bigcup U_n$ where $U_n$ are open, connected, and disjoint sets.

I've been trying to prove this, but I've encountered some problems:

(1) The exponential of a line $x=c$ is a circumference with radius $e^c$, this means that the boundary of $V$ is a line given by $x=\ln |z|$.

(2) It seems the inverse of $V$ through $\exp$ would be a set of the form $\{(x,0):0\leq x\leq |z|\}$

(3) Since $V$ is an open ball, it has all the points inside. I could virtually consider every possible circumference, but these are infinite and uncountable, which means I should consider infinite lines in the inverse, and because there are uncountable I cannot write it as an union of sets.

(4) I could "split" the set in disjoint open sets, for example something like $U_1=\{(x,0):0< x< |z|/2\}$ and $U_2=\{(x,0):|z|/2< x< |z|\}$, but is not true that the union of these is the inverse of $V$ because cirumferences would be missing. The problem here is the need to consider sets both open and disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $V$ is open and $ \exp$ is continuous, $\exp^{-1}(V)$ is open.

If only finitely many $U_n$ are allowed, put $U_1=\exp^{-1}(V)$ and we are done.

In the other case put

$ \mathcal B =\{B_r(q): r \in \mathbb Q, q \in \mathbb Q+i \mathbb Q\}$.

$ \mathcal B$ is countable ! Then there are $B_1,B_2,B_2, ... \in  \mathcal B$ such that

$\exp^{-1}(V)= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$.

For $k \in \mathbb N$ put

$U_k=\bigcup_{B_k \cap B_j \ne \emptyset}B_j$.

Then the sets $U_1,U_2, U_3,...$ have the desired property.